# XP unable to hibernate with system installed on LSI controller?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, raid, hibernate, acpi

I'm trying to build a workbench machine that will multi-boot all sorts of OSes, one of which will be XP32, SP3. So first up, please don't tell me how silly it is to be installing this nowadays, especially outside a VM, and I'm well aware. I need to be able to boot it on the raw metal on occasion, and that's non-negotiable. Mostly it will run in a VM anyway as I have the install working in both using hardware profiles.

To support expanding the storage dynamically, I've built it upon a LSI 9261 controller using RAID 5.

Now, the issue I'm having is that I'm unable to go into standby or hibernate in XP with said controller in place. I've been looking in powercfg for reasons, and comparing the output of `powercfg /devicequery all_devices` and `powercfg /devicequery s4_supported` gives a tiny subset:

```
LSI MR9261-8i SCSI Disk Device (001)
LSI MegaRAID Virtual Device (001)
Generic volume (001)
Generic volume (002)
Generic volume (003)
Generic volume (004)
Microsoft Kernel System Audio Device
Microsoft WINMM WDM Audio Compatibility Driver
```

Fair enough, I went looking at those devices in device manager and the power state mappings are "Unspecified". Strangely though, the `LSI MegaRAID SAS 9261-8i` device is listed as supporting the s4 state.

So on a hunch I pulled the controller and used another drive to do a comparison install to rule out compatibility elsewhere (BIOS settings, etc). This install can hibernate and standby perfectly, suggesting rather strongly the controller is the problem, or at least the disk devices for it.

I decided to have a gander at the powercfg output for comparison, and was surprised to find the following:

```
Crucial_ CT480M500SSD1 SCSI Disk Device
Generic volume
Generic volume (001)
Generic volume (002)
Microsoft Kernel Audio Splitter
Microsoft Kernel Acoustic Echo Canceller
Microsoft Kernel GS Wavetable Synthesizer
Microsoft Kernel DLS Synthesizer
Microsoft Kernel System Audio Device
Microsoft Kernel Wave Audio Mixer
Microsoft WINMM WDM Audio Compatibility Driver
Microsoft Kernel DRM Audio Descrambler
```

Now, I'm not sure what's going on with the audio differences, but ignoring those shows that the Generic Volume devices can't be relevant as they're present in both, leaving the sole differences as:

```
LSI MR9261-8i SCSI Disk Device (001)
LSI MegaRAID Virtual Device (001)
```

vs

```
Crucial_ CT480M500SSD1 SCSI Disk Device
```

Even weirder is that the drivers for the disk devices are Microsoft drivers (Disk.sys and PartMgr.sys), so you'd expect them to support hibernate fine, and the virtual device has no drivers!

So I'm at a bit of loss. I'm not going to be using this install on the bare metal much so it's not the end of the world if I can't get standby/hibernate working (as I can just suspend it in a VM), and hibernate works in Win7 and Linux (which will be my primary base OS uses on here), but I really don't like unsolved mysteries...

**--UPDATE--**

On a hunch I just tried adding in the LSI controller to the successfully hibernating install, and it works. As expected the usual diff of the powercfg outputs was:

```
Crucial_ CT480M500SSD1 SCSI Disk Device
LSI MR9261-8i SCSI Disk Device
RAID Virtual Device
Generic volume (001)
Generic volume (002)
Generic volume (003)
Generic volume (004)
Generic volume (005)
Generic volume (006)
Microsoft Kernel System Audio Device
Microsoft WINMM WDM Audio Compatibility Driver
```

...so it seems the issue may in fact just be having a system disk on the LSI controller? If so, it seems a very strange restriction. I have hibernate and standby working fine on another machine where the system disk is on an old Adaptec controller...

Comment: Always the way, isn't it? You give up, type up a long post somewhere, then a few minutes later have a bright idea.

I just changed the drivers for these ones:
http://www.avagotech.com/docs-and-downloads/raid-controllers/raid-controllers-common-files/MID_1433937_XP_x86_Signed_Driver_4-32-0-32.zip

...and it appears to be working now. Go figure. I'll leave this post as a reference. :)

Comment: This is called rubber duck debugging, @mr_jrt